# File Exists, but "No Such file Or Directory"

Tags: linux, file, assembly, nasm

```
[root@GoodiesArch ASM]# ls
EXEC*  file.sh*  this.asm
[root@GoodiesArch ASM]# ./EXEC 
bash: ./EXEC: No such file or directory
[root@GoodiesArch ASM]#
```

I have an assemblyfile that I compiled and it does not see it as an actual file. Not that I used [TAB] autofill to fill in the file name. It detects it, but it says "No such file or directory"

Here is what I am using to compile it.
I have a x64 bit machine and am running 32 bit asm code:

```
nasm -f elf32 -o tmp.o this.asm
ld -s -lc -L /usr/lib32/ -m elf_i386 -o EXEC tmp.o
```

It shows the file in `ls` and tabbing, but when I hit enter, it shows nothing.

**Update:**
Alright. When I do NOT call C functions via the ASM file, I can compile it and run, without error, using this:

```
nasm -f elf32 -o tmp.o this.asm
ld -s -m elf_i386 -o EXEC tmp.o
```

Comment: If it wasn't a binary I'd say it might have a bad she-bang line, but with a binary I'm out of ideas.

Comment: It is, indeed, a binary. I can execute the shell script fine. I should update it that I can execute it if I complile it differently, but the program won't allow me to.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a dynamic linker issue. Try executing it with `/usr/lib32` added to the dynamic link path:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib32 ./EXEC
```

If that doesn't work, you might be able to do something like:

```
/usr/lib32/ld-linux.so.2 --library-path /usr/lib32 ./EXEC
```